# Highcharts adjust y-axis to set "100%" as the sum of custom values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know that the title sounds confusing, but it wasn't easy finding a sentence for this problem, so I'll try to explain further.

I am trying to display a history of how many test cases there have been created for each day for given platforms. The y value reprents amount of current test cases while the "expected" is the the amount of test cases each serie require in order to reach the goal.

Can I somehow make y-axis display the expected value? So let's if I want to look at the IOS serie only, then it should know that the moment y and expected are identical it should fill 100% and not 12% of the plot. The same goes for when 2 test cases have been created while the expected value is 6, then it should fill 33% and not 2%.

http://jsfiddle.net/dWDE6/1201/

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y} / {point.expected}</b><br/>',
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    title: {
      text: 'Test cases'
    },
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value + "%";
      }
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'IOS',
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 15),
      y: 2,
      expected: 6
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 16),
      y: 3,
      expected: 6
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 17),
      y: 6,
      expected: 6
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Android',
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 15),
      y: 2,
      expected: 12
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 16),
      y: 3,
      expected: 12
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 17),
      y: 12,
      expected: 12
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Windows',
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 15),
      y: 6,
      expected: 12
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 16),
      y: 8,
      expected: 12
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 17),
      y: 14,
      expected: 12
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve what you are after.

http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/dWDE6/1202/

I changed your point style to the following:

```
actual: 2,
expected: 6,
y: 2/6*100
```

And the following pointFormat:

```
pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.actual} / {point.expected}</b><br/>'
```